# What is the null geodesic equation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, geodesics

What is null geodesic equation for the static and spherically symmetric line element in

$$ds^{2}=-K^{2}dt^{2}+\frac{dr^{2}}{K^{2}}+r^{2}(d\theta^{2}+\sin^{2}\theta{d\phi^{2}})$$

where

$$K^{2}=1-\frac{2M}{r}-\Lambda r^{2}+2 a r$$

Does anyone know how to derive the null geodesic equation for the above metric?
The result was given [here](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20140009252.pdf) without derivation as
$$\frac{d^{2}u}{d\phi^{2}}+u=3M u^{2}-a$$

where

$$u=\frac{1}{r}$$

I am trying to derive the above equation. First I started by setting $ds^{2}=0$, because null geodesic. Then I divided by $d\phi^{2}$. This is the equation I got

$$\frac{dr}{d\phi}=\sqrt{K^{2}r^{2}\sin^{2}\theta}$$

Assuming that $\frac{dt}{d\phi}=\frac{d\theta}{d\phi}=0$, is this a correct assumption?

Now Assuming that My calculation is correct so far does anyone know how to get the equation
$$\frac{d^{2}u}{d\phi^{2}}+u=3M u^{2}-a$$

Comment: What have you done to derive this yourself? What is the problem in deriving it?

Comment: I don't know where to start to derive the equation.

Comment: Can you write the metric from the line element? If so, it should be no problem, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_in_general_relativity

Comment: Can you give us a bit more background. From your previous posts you're obviously learning GR but still at an early stage. Do you know what the geodesic equation is and how it's used? Have you read [the Wikipedia article on calculating geodesics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solving_the_geodesic_equations)?

Comment: @ACuriousMind, I have edited my question

Comment: This question is not a duplicate.

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate (because the metrics are different), the answers there tell you how to derive it. This seems to have gone from a duplicate to "do this work for me," which is equally off-topic.

Comment: You have to calculate the Christoffel symbols from the metric, then feed them into the geodesic equation. That should give you the equation mentioned in the paper. The working is routine but rather tedious so I doubt anyone will feel enthusiastic about doing it for you.