# The null geodesic for given geodesic

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, geodesics

What is null geodesic equation for the static and spherically symmetric line element in

$$ds^{2}=-K^{2}dt^{2}+\frac{dr^{2}}{K^{2}}+r^{2}(d\theta^{2}+\sin^{2}\theta{d\phi^{2}})$$

where

$$K^{2}=1-\frac{2M}{r}-\Lambda r^{2}+2 a r$$

Does anyone know how to derive the null geodesic equation for the above metric?
The result was given [here](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20140009252.pdf) without derivation as
$$\frac{d^{2}u}{d\phi^{2}}+u=3M u^{2}-a$$

where

$$u=\frac{1}{r}$$

I am trying to derive the above equation. First I started by setting $ds^{2}=0$, because null geodesic. Then I divided by $d\phi^{2}$. This is the equation I got

$$\frac{dr}{d\phi}=\sqrt{K^{2}r^{2}\sin^{2}\theta}$$

Assuming that $\frac{dt}{d\phi}=\frac{d\theta}{d\phi}=0$, is this a correct assumption?

Now Assuming that My calculation is correct so far does anyone know how to get the equation
$$\frac{d^{2}u}{d\phi^{2}}+u=3M u^{2}-a$$

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/191164/2451

Comment: Hi Anonymous. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that.

Comment: @Qmechanic, could unmark that last question as duplicate.